# Error with making method in a class

Tags: java, methods

Trying to make a method that will take a user guess string input, and turn it into 
integer array.

```
  public int[] convertNumtoDigitArray()   //Java saying this line is a problem (The method convertNumToDigitArray() is undefined for the type engine
{
    String[] userGuessSplit = Player.userGuess.split(",");
    int[] userGuessArray = new int[userGuessSplit.length];
    for (int j=0; j<userGuessSplit.length; j++)
    {
        userGuessArray[j] = Integer.parseInt(userGuessSplit[j]);
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Where's your return value?

Comment: For your next question, you should copy-paste the compiler error instead of inlining a comment "Java saying this line is a problem", try "Java saying error you need to return stuff" :)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Just editted

Comment: @MikeJ: can you also add the surrounding class definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return anything, but you say that you will return an `int[]`.

```
public int[] convertNumtoDigitArray()   //Java saying this line is a problem
{
    String[] userGuessSplit = Player.userGuess.split(",");
    int[] userGuessArray = new int[userGuessSplit.length];
    for (int j=0; j<userGuessSplit.length; j++)
    {
        userGuessArray[j] = Integer.parseInt(userGuessSplit[j]);
    }
    return userGuessArray;
}
```

Comment: when i add the return statement it says Void methods cannot return a value. I'm also not trying to return the array, I just want to convert the original string that contains numbers to an array of the numbers

Comment: Then the code you provided is not your code; clearly you don't have `public int[] convertNumtoDigitArray()` and instead have `public void convertNumtoDigitArray()`. Huge difference between the two. As others say, please provide the error and relevant code.

Comment: im sorry, i just noticed I had an extra "}" from a for statement, which was throwing off my code. Really sorry about the trouble.

Comment: @MikeJ My answer doesn't provide that solution, so it isn't really a best answer. Maybe answer your question and explain that you made a typo. I'm glad to hear that you solved it though

Answer (score 0):

At the time of method creation you declared that your method will return the int[] type value. But till the last line your method is not returning the same or as it needs. 
  So return int[] value and your problem will get resolved.

use the return statement for return something from the method.